# How to remove bot pagination response in discord.py

Tags: python, pagination, discord, bots, discord.py

So I am using [disputils](https://pypi.org/project/disputils/) and I've made a pagination embed. however, after it gets inactive the reactions get auto removed by the bot. I want to make the bot remove the whole embed but I've tried a lot of things such as using `delete_after=(float)` and even asyncio but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
@commands.group(aliases = ['ra'])
    async def red(self, ctx):
        if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
            default = discord.Embed(title="`test`",color=discord.Colour.dark_red())
            default.set_image(url="foo")
            default.set_footer(text="Image by| user")
            
            v1 = discord.Embed(title="example", description='test', color=discord.Colour.dark_red())
            v1.set_footer(text="Info taken from| website")
            
            v2 = discord.Embed(title="spam", description="foo" ,color=discord.Colour.dark_red())
            v2.set_footer(text="Info taken from| website")
            embeds = [
                default,
                v1,
                v2,           
            ]
            paginator = BotEmbedPaginator(ctx, embeds)
            await paginator.run()
```

I tried using `delete_after(float)` inside the paranthesis of `await paginator.run()` doesn't work. tried using it asycnio format and got an error `Instance of 'BotEmbedPaginator' has no 'delete' member`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just use [DiscordUtils](https://pypi.org/projects/DiscordUtils/)**

Here is an example:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def paginate(self, ctx):
        embed1 = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color).add_field(name="Example", value="Page 1")
        embed2 = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color).add_field(name="Example", value="Page 2")
        embed3 = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color).add_field(name="Example", value="Page 3")
        paginator = DiscordUtils.Pagination.CustomEmbedPaginator(ctx, remove_reactions=True)
        paginator.add_reaction('⏮️', "first")
        paginator.add_reaction('⏪', "back")
        paginator.add_reaction('', "lock")
        paginator.add_reaction('⏩', "next")
        paginator.add_reaction('⏭️', "last")
        embeds = [embed1, embed2, embed3]
        await paginator.run(embeds)
```

Comment: The link is wrong by the way. https://pypi.org/project/DiscordUtils/ this is the correct one you added an `s` after project :) . anyways thank you very much also would be good if you can edit it so someone else can use ur comment in the future